# Convert html5 <canvas> image to bitmap usable in drawImage

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I want to save canvas image as a bitmap to be able to later use it in drawImage.

Goal is to be able to change (eg. resize) canvas and keep it's contents (eg. scaled - canvas is always a square).

I tried:
`var tmp = createImageBitmap(canvas)`
`ctx.drawImage(tmp,0,0)`

What I got was an error that said 'tmp' is not a bitmap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[createImageBitmap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/createImageBitmap) returns a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), so the result is asynchronous and you have to wait for it with `await`:

```js
const img = await createImageBitmap(canvas);
ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
```

Or if you can't use `await` because you target ES5 then do it the old fashioned way:

```js
createImageBitmap(canvas).then(img => {
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

An `HTMLCanvasElement` is part of the `CanvasImageSource` mixin, meaning you can directly use it with `drawImage()`:

```js
const [canvas1, canvas2] = document.querySelectorAll("canvas");
const ctx1 = canvas1.getContext("2d");
const ctx2 = canvas2.getContext("2d");

ctx1.fillStyle = "green"
ctx1.fillRect(0, 0, 50, 50);

ctx2.fillStyle = "red"
ctx2.fillRect(0, 0, 50, 50);
// draw canvas1 at (60, 0), with a 2x scale
ctx2.drawImage(canvas1, 60, 0, 600, 300);
```

```css
canvas { border: 1px solid }
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
<canvas></canvas>
```